# How to get data from JSON with different keys?

Tags: json, swift, swift3

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
"00AK": {
    "icao": "00AK",
    "iata": "",
    "name": "Lowell Field",
    "city": "Anchor Point",
    "country": "US",
    "elevation": 450,
    "lat": 59.94919968,
    "lon": -151.695999146,
    "tz": "America\/Anchorage"
},
"00AL": {
    "icao": "00AL",
    "iata": "",
    "name": "Epps Airpark",
    "city": "Harvest",
    "country": "US",
    "elevation": 820,
    "lat": 34.8647994995,
    "lon": -86.7703018188,
    "tz": "America\/Chicago"
},
"00AZ": {
    "icao": "00AZ",
    "iata": "",
    "name": "Cordes Airport",
    "city": "Cordes",
    "country": "US",
    "elevation": 3810,
    "lat": 34.3055992126,
    "lon": -112.1650009155,
    "tz": "America\/Phoenix"
}
}
```

As you can see the keys varies "00AK", "00AL", "00AZ", and so on. How do I parse this format of JSON?

Comment: Refer - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: what do the keys matter to parsing? Just parse the json like any other, id your actual question how to retrieve the data from the parsed json?

Comment: you can google it, search keyword jsonObject. there is tons of sample out there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let jsonData = //JSON DATA HERE
do {
    let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! NSDictionary
    for (key, value) in dict {
        let subDict = value as! NSDictionary
        //Then you can access the values from subDict
    } catch {
        //ERROR HANDLING    
    }
```

Comment: You should not use NSDictionary in Swift, better use a Swift dictionary like `[String: Any]`. Also you should not force cast but instead handle the possible casting failure.

Comment: Agreed. I was just giving the basic gist of the process.

Answer (score 0):

So here it is I declare one structure as following

```
struct Model {
var iaco: String?
var iata: String?
var name: String?
var city: String?
var country: String?
var elevation: Int?
var lat: Double?
var lon: Double?
var tz: String? }
```

Then declare on array to hold the response result

```
var listOfModels = Array<Model>()
```

Then take a list of keys from response Dictionary and iterate over it to get result and store it in array

```
  handleResponse { (response) in
        for key in response.keys {
            let dict = response[key] as? [String:Any]
            var model = Model()
            model.iaco = dict?["icao"] as? String
            model.iata = dict?["iata"] as? String
            model.name = dict?["name"] as? String
            model.city = dict?["city"] as? String
            model.country = dict?["country"] as? String
            model.elevation = dict?["elevation"] as? Int
            model.lat = dict?["lat"] as? Double
            model.lon = dict?["lon"] as? Double
            model.tz = dict?["tz"] as? String
            listOfModels.append(model)
        }
    }
```

response.keys is used to get list of keys from dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below snippet:

```
func parseData() {
    let jsonData = Data() /// your actual response data goes here...
    do {
        let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments)
        guard let swiftDict = dict as? [String : Any] else {
            print("Not a valid response")
            return
        }

        for (key, value) in swiftDict {
            guard let valueDict = value as? [String: Any] else {
                /// handle improper response here
                return
            }

            /// Got the actual dictionary in 'valueDict'...
        }
    }
    catch {
            /// handle parsing error here
    }

}
```